# Video format usage in videoview

Tags: android, eclipse, android-videoview, 3gp

I am building an application that deals with thousands of videos and am wanting to know what the fastest video format is for Android eclipse. I currently use .3gp. Also I put my code up, so if anybody has any suggestions about it, fell free to comment.

Thank you so much

Comment: hey scott1218 eclipse supported all video format so you can put any type of video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the Document**

As an application developer, you are free to make use of any media codec that is available on any Android-powered device, including those provided by the Android platform and those that are device-specific. However, `it is a best practice to use media encoding profiles that are device-agnostic.`

[Video Encoding Recommendations](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations)